# $modalStack not closing modal when clicking back button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

I am using AngularUI bootstrap modal which is opened from my controller as below:

```
$scope.openModal = $modal({
            title: title,
            scope: $scope,
            templateUrl: modalUrl,
            html: true,
            show: false,
            backdrop: 'static'
        });

$scope.openModal.$promise.then($scope.openModal.show);
```

I am trying to close my modal when clicking back button in browser by following code in app.js:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$modalStack', function ($rootScope, $modalStack) {
   $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
       var top = $modalStack.getTop();
       if (top) {
           $modalStack.dismiss(top.key);
       }
   });
}]);
```

But in the above code, `$modalStack.getTop()` always returns as `undefined` though my modal stays opened.

I have also tried using `$rootScope` for opening modal. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: $modalStack.dismissAll(); // this will dismiss All the opend modals on route change

Comment: But $modalStack itself returning undefined. How would dismissAll() would work?